# Failed to get text inside image with kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I try to build a scanner image project using  kotlin / java sprintboot

and i have tried to found the way to create a method to read a text inside a image and atleast i found 3 ways, but all i tried and i failed :

1. Using Aspose.OCR
   [ASPOSE](https://releases.aspose.com/ocr/java/) and [ASPOSE 2](https://kb.aspose.com/ocr/java/how-to-extract-text-from-image-using-java/), i got error when i tried to add a dependency at pom.xml
   [image]
2. Using [tessj4](https://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/) and i allready follow but still failed
   [image]

and here is my code :

```
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;

val instance:ITesseract = Tesseract();
instance.setDatapath(basedir + "/tessdata");
instance.setLanguage("eng"); 
//val tessDataFolder:File = LoadLibs.extractTessResources("tessdata");

//Set the tessdata path
//instance.setDatapath(tessDataFolder.getAbsolutePath());

val imageText:String = instance.doOCR(File(filename));
```

here is my dependency i add

[image]

3. Using [org.bytedeco.javacpp](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract.TessBaseAPI), i already can get text inside the image, but the text i got is very different between the text i got and the text inside image

Here is my Code

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract.*;

var outText : BytePointer;
var api : TessBaseAPI = TessBaseAPI();
var imagePix:PIX = pixRead(filename);
api.Init(null, "eng");//api.Init(null, "ind")
api.SetImage(imagePix);
outText = api.GetUTF8Text();
val imageText:String = outText.getString("UTF-8");//outText.getString();
```

Here is my dependency i add

[image: org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets tesseract-platform 3.04.01-1.3]

Here is image example that i want to get the text (i had blur some content) :

[image]

Am I missing something??

I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For Aspose.OCR for Java, can you please make sure that your pom.xml file has following sections defined correctly:

```
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
  <name>Aspose Java API</name>
  <url>https://releases.aspose.com/java/repo/</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspose-ocr</artifactId>
  <version>23.5.0</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For further information, please also check [installation section](https://docs.aspose.com/ocr/java/installation/#installing-asposeocr-for-java-from-maven-repository) of the API documentation. In case you still face any issues, please create a new topic in official [Aspose.OCR support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/ocr) where you will be assisted accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: ok, i will try it first